# Python: reading in a csv file and saving columns as variables

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I'm wanting to read in a csv and save the first two columns as variables.
This is what I have so far:

```
import sys, os, subprocess, shutil, time, string #these are for other things in the program :)
import csv

csvfile = list(csv.reader(open('test.csv')))   #read in the csv file

csv_dic = []

for row in csvfile:
        csv_dic.append(row);

for row in csv_dic:
       for column in row:
             print column, "***",   #I can print out the column
       print
```

I can print out columns, but would like to have it so I can have different variables for column 'arrays'.

For example, I am wanting to store the first column as 'frames' and the second as 'peaks', so to **have it so, for example, frames[2] holds the second value in the first column** and I can reference it.

Thank you.

Comment: better to tokenize to a `dict` and use the key's as your names and the values as your columns

Comment: Is it important that these be variables or should they be members of a `dict`? Do you know the names of the variables before hand?

Comment: @tdelaney it would only make sense that all the variables on the same column will have the same variable name and different values - doesn't it ?

Comment: @alfasin sure, but that has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Its common for csv files to have a header line that is then used as a column name. Is that the case here?

Comment: @tdelaney no column names in this csv file, sorry!

Comment: No need to be sorry, I'm just trying to figure out where the variable name come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
frames = []
peaks = []

for row in csv_dic:
    frames.append(row[0])
    peaks.append(row[1])
    for column in row:
        print column, "***",   #I can print out the column
    print
```

Note that I am making one big assumption: that the two columns you want are exactly the first two columns of the CSV file. But this should do what you want. `row[0]` is the value in the first column of the row, and likewise, `row[1]` is the second column.

Now, if you want to do an unknown number of columns, you'll have to use another method (like a dictionary, perhaps).

Comment: Thank you, assuming the first 2 columns in the file is perfectly fine. question, if I want to access a specific element in the column, can I do something like row[1][2]?

Comment: Actually, you can't. `row` is a one-dimensional list, so all you can do is `row[1]`. Now, you *can* do something like `csv_dic[4][1]`, where `csv_dic[4]` is the fifth row.

Comment: So csv_dic[4][1] will give me the 5th element in the 2nd column? As in, column 2, row 5?

Comment: Ok, so what exactly would something like peaks[1] and peaks[2] hold?

Comment: `peaks[1]` will have `csv_dic[1][1]`. The second column of the second row. Likewise, `peaks[2]` will have `csv_dic[2][1]`. `frames` is for the first column, so `frames[2]` is `csv_dic[2][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple to do with the `CSV` module which you are already using. Here is a dictionary method and an array method.

**dictionary**

```
import csv
var1 = "frames"
var2 = "peaks"
csv_dic={var1:[], var2:[]}
csvFile = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rb'))
for row in csvFile:
  csv_dic[var1].append(row[0])
  csv_dic[var2].append(row[1])
```

again assuming that you only are worried about first two elements of each row.

Here is a method that will get you everything into your array, here called `data`. This is relatively fast for large files.

**array**

```
import csv
with open('test.csv','rb') as file:
    rows = csv.reader(file, 
                      delimiter = ',', 
                      quotechar = '"')
    data = [data for data in rows]
```

Comment: What if I want to store all the elements (in a large number of rows) for the first two columns?