# what does 'rb' mean in csv files?

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
with open('test.csv','rb') as file:
    rows = csv.reader(file, 
                      delimiter = ',', 
                      quotechar = '"')
    data = [data for data in rows]
```

This was in [Python: reading in a csv file and saving columns as variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928399/python-reading-in-a-csv-file-and-saving-columns-as-variables). I couldn't comment, but I'm really confused. What does 'rb' mean?

Comment: Quite a few questions on this, e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746954/what-is-the-difference-between-rb-and-rb-modes-in-file-objects)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It means: **R**ead the file in **B**inary mode.

For a complete list of options view [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 4):

From [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) in the Built-in functions documentation:

> **open(name[, mode[, buffering]])**
>
> The most commonly-used values of mode are `'r'` for reading, (...) Thus,
>   when opening a binary file, you should append `'b'` to the mode value
>   to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability.

So this opens the file to read in a binary mode.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument o `open()` is the `mode` the file will be opened in. `'rb'` is for Read Binary mode. Read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)